# How i can scrape a mobile number and Email from an hidden html tags?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I work on a small project to scrape some data from a website, everything seems to work well, but I can't scrape the mobile number it shows me a blank output in some cases and full HTML tags with the mobile phone in other cases.

I want to scrape the phone number along with other data, all the data get scraped correctly except the mobile phone.
Here is the output I get:

`Name: Klinik Seeschau AG Address: Bernrainstrasse 17, 8280 Kreuzlingen Phone:`

Here is my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# navigate to the URL
driver.get("https://www.local.ch/en/",)

# Searching for "Clinic"
def search_query(query):
    search = driver.find_element("name", "what")
    search.clear()
    time.sleep(3)
    search.send_keys(query)
    time.sleep(3)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)

# extract the source code
def source():
    source_code = driver.page_source
    # Sleep for 3 second 
    time.sleep(3)
    # parse the source code with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
    time.sleep(3)

# Extracting the data
def datasearch():
    searchResult = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "search-header-results")
    data = searchResult.text
    print(f"there's {data}\n")
    time.sleep(2)

# Get the phone_numbers elements
def data_scrape():
    # data = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-xs-12.col-md-8")
    # Loop in data end extract phone numbers
    components = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-entry-card-container.row.lui-margin-vertical-xs.lui-sm-margin-vertical-m")
    for component in components:
        name = component.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lui-margin-vertical-zero.card-info-title").text
        addre = component.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-info-address").text
        phone = component.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lui-sm-margin-left-xxs").text
        print(f"Name: {name}\nAddress: {addre}\n Phone: {phone}\n")



# Sleep for 2 second
search_query("Clinique")
source()
datasearch()
data_scrape()
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Why don't you try clicking on **Show Number** to bring out the visible number to scrape it easily?

Comment: I guess clicking on the element isn't a good approach bcz numbers are shown without clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get that information, based on your existing code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# navigate to the URL
driver.get("https://www.local.ch/en/",)

# Searching for "Clinic"
def search_query(query):
    search = driver.find_element("name", "what")
    search.clear()
    time.sleep(3)
    search.send_keys(query)
    time.sleep(3)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)

# extract the source code
def source():
    source_code = driver.page_source
    # Sleep for 3 second 
    time.sleep(3)
    # parse the source code with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
    time.sleep(3)

# Extracting the data
def datasearch():
    searchResult = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "search-header-results")
    data = searchResult.text
    print(f"there's {data}\n")
    time.sleep(2)

# Get the phone_numbers elements
def data_scrape():
    # data = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "col-xs-12.col-md-8")
    # Loop in data end extract phone numbers
    components = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-entry-card-container.row.lui-margin-vertical-xs.lui-sm-margin-vertical-m")
    for component in components:
        name = component.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lui-margin-vertical-zero.card-info-title").text
        addre = component.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-info-address").text
        phone = component.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@title="Call"]').get_attribute('href').split('tel:')[1] if component.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@title="Call"]') else None
        print(f"Name: {name}\nAddress: {addre}\n Phone: {phone}\n")



# Sleep for 2 second
search_query("Clinique")
source()
datasearch()
data_scrape()
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Result in terminal:

```
there's 2013 results for Clinique in Switzerland, in French

Name: HerzKlinik Hirslanden
Address: Witellikerstrasse 40, 8008 Zürich
 Phone: +41443879700

Name: Berner Klinik Montana - Clinique Bernoise Montana
Address: Impasse Palace Bellevue 1, 3963 Crans-Montana
 Phone: +41274855288

Name: PZM Psychiatriezentrum Münsingen AG
Address: Hunzigenallee 1, 3110 Münsingen
 Phone: +41317208111

Name: Spitalzentrum Biel AG
Address: Vogelsang 84, 2502 Biel/Bienne
 Phone: +41323242424

Name: LipoFilling
Address: Dammstrasse 29, 8702 Zollikon
 Phone: +41443971717

Name: Adipositas und StoffwechselZentrum Zürich
Address: Witellikerstrasse 36, 8008 Zürich
 Phone: +41443874000

Name: Maison Tóā - Clinique esthétique
Address: Voie du Chariot 6, 1003 Lausanne
 Phone: +41217917070

Name: Klinik Seeschau AG
Address: Bernrainstrasse 17, 8280 Kreuzlingen
 Phone: +41716775353

Name: Clinica Holistica Engiadina SA
Address: Plaz 40, 7542 Susch
 Phone: +41813002030

Name: Kantonsspital Baselland Liestal
Address: Rheinstrasse 26, 4410 Liestal
 Phone: +41619252525
```

You can find Selenium documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Comment: yeah, thank you I have already done the same approach to get things done `phone = component.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Call']").get_attribute("href").replace("tel:", "")`

Comment: Optimized code & much cleaner +1